# WPF binding issue inside datagrid column with custom control

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a NumericBox custom control that has a StatusMessage dependency property -

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusMessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StatusMessage", typeof(string), typeof(EditBoxBase), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, UiPropertyChanged));

    public string StatusMessage
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(StatusMessageProperty);
        set => SetValue(StatusMessageProperty, value);
    }
```

NumericBox XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type impinj:EditBoxBase}}}">
    <controls:TextBox x:Name="InnerTextBox" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" MaxLength="20" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type impinj:EditBoxBase}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </controls:TextBox>
```

and the TextBox_TextChanged updates the StatusMessage.

This control is used in the MainWindow outside and inside a datagrid column and the issue is that the control inside the datagrid column does not update its status message on text change as the the control outside the datagrid column does (the latter being the expected behavior).

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewModels:MainViewModelDesigner x:Key="MainViewModelDesigner" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModelDesigner}}" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="LotGridRow" Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="ScrollableRegionHeaderRow" Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="ScrollableRegionRow" Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="LotGrid" Grid.Row="0" Margin="30,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="AngleBreakPrompt" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Angle Break: " HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <controls:NumericBox x:Name="AngleBreakCount" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AngleBreakCount1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="EditBoxBase_TextChanged" ValidationErrorMessage="Angle Break Validation Message #1" StatusMessage="{Binding AngleBreakCountStatusMessage1, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
    </Grid>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ScrollableRegion">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="ScrollableRegionGrid" d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModelDesigner}}" UseLayoutRounding="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="WaferHeaderRow" Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="WaferGridRow" Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="30,15,30,15" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                <DataGrid x:Name="WaferDataGrid" Margin="15,15,15,15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Wafers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FrozenColumnCount="1" HeadersVisibility="Column" Height="Auto" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" AlternatingRowBackground="#C4EBFF" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="false">
                   <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" x:Name="AngleBreakColumn">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <controls:NumericBox x:Name="AngleBreakCount" Text="{Binding AngleBreakCount2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="EditBoxBase_TextChanged" ValidationErrorMessage="Angle Break Validation Message #2" StatusMessage="{Binding AngleBreakCountStatusMessage2, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

From MainViewModel, which is the DataContext for the MainWindow and implements INotifyPropertyChanged -

```
    private ObservableCollection<Wafer> _waferCollection = new ObservableCollection<Wafer>();

    public ObservableCollection<Wafer> Wafers
    {
        get => _waferCollection;
        set
        {
            _waferCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _angleBreakCount1;

    public string AngleBreakCount1
    {
        get => _angleBreakCount1;
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:G}, In AngleBreakCount1 Setter");

            if (_angleBreakCount1 == value)
                return;
            _angleBreakCount1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _angleBreakCountStatusMessage1;

    public string AngleBreakCountStatusMessage1
    {
        get => _angleBreakCountStatusMessage1;
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:G}, In AngleBreakCountStatusMessage1 Setter");

            if (_angleBreakCountStatusMessage1 == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _angleBreakCountStatusMessage1 = value;               
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

From Wafer, which is the ItemsSource for the datagrid and also implements INotifyPropertyChanged -

```
    private string _angleBreakCount2;

    public string AngleBreakCount2
    {
        get => _angleBreakCount2;
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:G}, In AngleBreakCount2 Setter");

            if (_angleBreakCount2 == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _angleBreakCount2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _angleBreakCountStatusMessage2;

    public string AngleBreakCountStatusMessage2
    {
        get => _angleBreakCountStatusMessage2;
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:G}, In Elusive AngleBreakCountStatusMessage2 Setter");

            if (_angleBreakCountStatusMessage2 == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _angleBreakCountStatusMessage2 = value;               
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

When the text in the NumericBox inside the datagrid column and thereby, AngleBreakCount2 on Wafer bound to it is updated, AngleBreakCountStatusMessage2 on Wafer bound to its StatusMessage does not get updated. When the text in the NumericBox outside the datagrid column and thereby, AngleBreakCount1 on the MainViewModel bound to it is updated, AngleBreakCountStatusMessage1 on the MainViewModel bound to its StatusMessage does get updated, which is the desired behavior. Any idea as to why the NumericBox inside the datagrid column is not showing the desired behavior?